# Выражения "давать отчёт" и "отдавать отчёт"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

"Давать отчёт" или "отдавать отчёт" — как предпочтительнее?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это выражения с разным смыслом, употребляемые в разных ситуациях.

Выражение "**давать отчёт**" (кому-л.) имеет буквальный смысл "отчитываться" перед кем-то.

> Я не обязан давать вам отчёт, где я провёл/проведу вечер и с кем.

"**Отдавать *себе* отчёт**" - фразеологизм, означающий "осознавать" (понимать сложившуюся ситуацию, последствия своих действий или бездействия, свою ответственность).

> Вы отдаёте себе отчёт в том, что делаете (в том, к чему это может
>   привести)?

Answer (score 1):

**А. Существует прямое и переносное значение этих выражений**

**1) Прямое значение слова** (1) передавать документ, 2) отчитываться

― Братцы, что же это вы делаете? Как же я буду **отдавать отчет**? Пусть ваш начальник расписку мне даст, сколько и чего взято из арсенала. [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Капитан первого ранга (1936-1944)]

― Это значит, что я повинуюсь и обязан **отдавать отчет** в своих действиях одной государыне императрице. [Н. Э. Гейнце. Князь Тавриды (1898)]

**2) Переносное значение** (нести ответственность, понимать)

Однако следует отдавать отчет в том, что положение остается крайне неблагополучным.  Август-декабрь 1999 (1999)]

Вольный человек, не привык **давать отчёт** кому-либо в своих действиях, поступках и желаниях. [Виктор Астафьев. Затеси (1999) // «Новый Мир», 2000]

И если точно есть предопределение, то зачем нам дана воля, рассудок? почему мы должны **давать отчёт** в наших поступках? [М. Ю. Лермонтов. Герой нашего времени (1839-1841)]

**Б. Во многих случаях эти выражения взаимозаменяемы, но не всегда**

Например: "следует отдавать отчет" предпочтительнее, чем "следует давать отчёт", то есть приставка ОТ придает глаголу значение **"направленной ответственности", обязательности  и официальности.**

Comment: Объяснение гораздо более глубокое, чем то, что можно найти в каждом словаре, согласно которым "отдавать отчет" можно только себе.

Comment: Тем не менее, "в каждом словаре" объяснение правильное, а @Sibylla лишь фантазирует, хоть и глубоко.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе есть немало примеров, в которых "отдают отчет" не себе, а кому-то другому.  @Sibylla их объясняет. На чем основана ее теория - непонятно, но выглядит все логично.

Answer (score 0):

В одном из своих значений отчет - это некий документ, который можно давать, отдавать и т.д., так же как и любой другой предмет.